# Parasites with both plant and animal hosts?

Tags: parasitology

Are there animals (or plants) that are parasitic on both animals and plants?

Especially such that they rely on their plant host being eaten by their animal host?

Comment: haven't heard of a plant/animal like that... there are micro-organisms that wait to be ingested by animals to continue their life cycle though

Comment: My guess is that fungi would be the best candidate, without knowing about a particular answer/example to your question. I know that there are groups of parasitic fungi that have switched between animal and plant hosts (i.e. in relation to speciation events, not host switching/complex life cycles within the same species of fungi).

Comment: Plant to animal switching is known in e.g. rust fungi (from [Pucciniomycetes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pucciniomycetes)), where you can also find complex life cycles with intermediate hosts (a [Heteroecious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroecious) life cycle).